# Apply Hinge Loss & Low-Rank Positives loss with Graph Neural Network for Recommendation System

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, recommendation-engine, pytorch-geometric, gnn

I have a pytorch model I built for recommending best restaurants to user. I used graphSage and MSE as a loss between the predicted labels and the actual ones.

I want to apply the same loss mentioned on [Food Discovery with Uber Eats: Using Graph Learning to Power Recommendations](https://www.uber.com/en-DE/blog/uber-eats-graph-learning/)

[Uber Eats recommendation system leverages max-margin loss augmented with low rank positives.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Jpye.png)

Here's my code

```
from torch_geometric.nn import SAGEConv, to_hetero
import torch.nn.functional as F
import torch
import torch.nn as nn

# Our final classifier applies the dot-product between source and destination
# node embeddings to derive edge-level predictions:
class Predicter(torch.nn.Module):
  def __init__(self, in_channels, hidden_channels, out_channels, num_layers,dropout):
    super(Predicter, self).__init__()

    self.lins = nn.ModuleList()
    self.lins.append(nn.Linear(in_channels, hidden_channels))
    for _ in range(num_layers - 2):
        self.lins.append(nn.Linear(hidden_channels, hidden_channels))
    self.lins.append(nn.Linear(hidden_channels, out_channels))

    self.dropout = dropout

  def reset_parameters(self):
    for lin in self.lins:
        lin.reset_parameters()

  def forward(self, x_i, x_j):
    x = x_i * x_j
    for lin in self.lins[:-1]:
        x = lin(x)
        x = F.relu(x)
        x = F.dropout(x, p=self.dropout, training=self.training)
    x = self.lins[-1](x)
    return x
    # return torch.sigmoid(x)

class GNNStack(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_dim, hidden_dim, output_dim, num_layers, dropout, emb=False):
        super(GNNStack, self).__init__()
        conv_model = SAGEConv

        self.convs = nn.ModuleList()
        self.convs.append(conv_model(input_dim, hidden_dim))
        self.dropout = dropout
        self.num_layers = num_layers
        self.emb = emb

        # Create num_layers GraphSAGE convs
        assert (self.num_layers >= 1), 'Number of layers is not >=1'
        for l in range(self.num_layers - 1):
            self.convs.append(conv_model(hidden_dim, hidden_dim))

        # post-message-passing processing
        self.post_mp = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(hidden_dim, hidden_dim), nn.Dropout(self.dropout),
            nn.Linear(hidden_dim, output_dim))

    def forward(self, x, edge_index):
        for i in range(self.num_layers):
            x = self.convs[i](x, edge_index)
            x = F.relu(x)
            x = F.dropout(x, p=self.dropout, training=self.training)

        x = self.post_mp(x)

        # Return final layer of embeddings if specified
        
        return x

        # Else return class probabilities
        # return F.log_softmax(x, dim=1)

    def loss(self, pred, label):
        return F.nll_loss(pred, label)


class EdgeDecoder(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, hidden_channels):
        super().__init__()
        self.lin1 = Linear(hidden_channels, hidden_channels)
        self.lin2 = Linear(hidden_channels, 1)

    def forward(self, x_i, x_j):
        x = x_i * x_j
        x = self.lin1(x)
        x = F.relu(x)
        x = self.lin2(x)
        return x.view(-1)
        


class MainModel(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, data, user_input_size,
                 rest_input_size,
                 hidden_channels):
        super().__init__()
        # Since the dataset does not come with rich features, we also learn two
        # embedding matrices for users and movies:
        self.user_lin = torch.nn.Linear(in_features = user_input_size, out_features = hidden_channels)
        self.rest_lin = torch.nn.Linear(in_features = rest_input_size, out_features = hidden_channels)

        self.user_emb = torch.nn.Embedding(data["user"].num_nodes, hidden_channels)
        self.rest_emb = torch.nn.Embedding(data["restaurant"].num_nodes, hidden_channels)

        # Instantiate homogeneous GNN:
        self.gnn = GNNStack(hidden_channels, hidden_channels, hidden_channels, 4, 0.3, emb = True)
        # Convert GNN model into a heterogeneous variant:
        self.gnn = to_hetero(self.gnn, metadata=data.metadata())
        self.new_x_dict = None
    def forward(self,  train_data) -> Tensor:
        # `x_dict` holds feature matrices of all node types
        # `edge_index_dict` holds all edge indices of all edge types
        x_dict = {
          "user":  self.user_lin(train_data.x_dict["user"]) + self.user_emb(train_data["user"].node_id),
          "restaurant": self.rest_lin(train_data.x_dict["restaurant"]) + self.rest_emb(train_data["restaurant"].node_id),
        }

        self.new_x_dict = self.gnn(x_dict, train_data.edge_index_dict)
        return self.new_x_dict



import tqdm
from torch_geometric.utils import negative_sampling, batched_negative_sampling
device = torch.device('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')
optim_wd = 0
epochs = 20
hidden_dim = 256
dropout = 0.3
num_layers = 2
lr = 0.01
node_emb_dim = 256


model  = MainModel(train_data, user_input_size= train_data['user'].x.shape[1],
                   rest_input_size = train_data['restaurant'].x.shape[1],
                   hidden_channels=64).to(device)

predicter = EdgeDecoder(hidden_channels = 64).to(device) 

optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(
    list(model.parameters()) + list(predicter.parameters()),
    lr=lr, weight_decay=optim_wd)


losses = []
vallosses=[]
import torch.nn.functional as F


for epoch in range(epochs):
  total_loss = 0 
  for batch in tqdm.tqdm(train_loader):
    optimizer.zero_grad()

    pos_edges = batch['user', 'rates', 'restaurant'].edge_label_index
    labels = batch['user', 'rates', 'restaurant'].edge_label

    model.train()
    predicter.train()
    optimizer.zero_grad()

    node_emb = model(batch)
    # Predict the class probabilities on the batch of positive edges using link_predictor
    # Apply the weight to the positive loss term
    pos_pred = predicter(node_emb['user'][pos_edges[0]], node_emb['restaurant'][pos_edges[1]])
    loss =F.mse_loss(pos_pred.view(-1).float(), labels)
    # Backpropagate and update parameters
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()

      
    total_loss += float(loss) 
    
  print(f"Epoch {epoch + 1}: Train loss: {total_loss} ")
```

Any helpful tip would be appreciated!

I tried to build hinge loss by this way.

```
for epoch in range(epochs):
  total_loss = 0 
  for batch in tqdm.tqdm(train_loader):
    optimizer.zero_grad()

    pos_edges = batch['user', 'rates', 'restaurant'].edge_label_index
    labels = batch['user', 'rates', 'restaurant'].edge_label

    #Get the nodes that are present in the current batch
    src_nodes_in_batch = set(pos_edges[0].flatten().tolist())
    dst_nodes_in_batch = set(pos_edges[1].flatten().tolist())  
    # Perform negative sampling for the current batch, using only the nodes that are present in the batch
    neg_edges = negative_sampling(pos_edges, num_nodes=(len(src_nodes_in_batch), len(dst_nodes_in_batch)), method='dense')

    model.train()
    predicter.train()

    optimizer.zero_grad()

    node_emb = model(batch)
    # Predict the class probabilities on the batch of positive edges using link_predictor
    # Apply the weight to the positive loss term
    pos_pred = predicter(node_emb['user'][pos_edges[0]], node_emb['restaurant'][pos_edges[1]])
    neg_pred = predicter(node_emb['user'][neg_edges[0]], node_emb['restaurant'][neg_edges[1]])

    # Combine the positive and negative loss terms
    loss = -((torch.log(pos_pred + 1e-15)) * labels).mean() - ((torch.log(1 - neg_pred + 1e-15))).mean()
    # Backpropagate and update parameters
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()

      
    total_loss += float(loss) 
    
  print(f"Epoch {epoch + 1}: Train loss: {total_loss} ")
```